# SELinux Issue - git status fatal: Out of memory? mmap failed: Permission denied

Tags: centos, git, selinux

I have Centos 7.9 server running with Apache and Git, however if I do a

```
[root@a]# git status
fatal: Out of memory? mmap failed: Permission denied
```

But if Disable or Permissive the SE-Linux via below commands it start working fine.

```
setenforce Permissive
```

Any idea on how to fix this issue permanently with SELinux enabled?

Audit log says

```
node=a type=PROCTITLE msg=audit(1630636505.296:37076): proctitle=67697400737461747573
node=a type=MMAP msg=audit(1630636505.296:37076): fd=3 flags=0x2
node=a type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1630636505.296:37076): arch=c000003e syscall=9 success=no exit=-13 a0=0 a1=3ebd0 a2=3 a3=2 items=0 ppid=8008 pid=8156 auid=1001 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=pts0 ses=570 comm="git" exe="/usr/bin/git" subj=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 key=(null)
node=a type=AVC msg=audit(1630636505.296:37076): avc:  denied  { map } for  pid=8156 comm="git" path="/www/site/.git/index" dev="sda2" ino=540400 scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0
```

Comment: Root is normally unconfined. Can you provide the result of `id -Z`?

Comment: Check the audit log.

Comment: @MichaelHampton  I added the audit log into it says something abt 
scontext=unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tcontext=unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=0

Comment: @MatthewIfe it says unconfined_u:unconfined_r:unconfined_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is this file you're mapping:

```
/www/site/.git/index
```

This file has the type `httpd_t` however that isn't actually a legitimate file type but is a process (or domain type as its known) instead.

You should probably set the context of `/www` as being `httpd_sys_content_t` or if you want to allow the webserver to write to it `httpd_sys_content_rw_t`.

If I had to guess, I'm going to assume you did a `chcon -t httpd_t` on `/www` in error.

The best approach to fix this properly will be to reset and restore the file contexts:

```
# semanage fcontext -a -t httpd_sys_content_t '/www(/.*)?'
# restorecon -rv /www
```

This should set the correct context and prevent future context mishaps.

Then test the `git status` again to check it worked.

Comment: yeah i ran this, 'sudo chcon -Rv --type=httpd_t /www/'